# Extract a Value from an Element based on other value from an Element of an Node in Bash

Tags: xml, bash, android-layout

I want to extract Text from a node and have several Nodes within the XML file.
Luckly the resource-id of the Node i need to extract the textvalue from is always the same.

So essentially I want to input the resource-id ("com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/hzk") and as an output i would get the text from the node ("exampletext").

I know how I could do this in python, but have 0 idea how to do it in a bash script.

This is how the Node looks:

```
<node index="1" text="exampletext" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/hzk" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[231,434][753,481]" /></node>
```

the XML-File has several nodes and is completely unorganized as a text block:

```
(...)
class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[231,1622][753,1669]" /></node><node index="2" text="Follow" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/fig" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[794,1579][1036,1656]" /></node><node index="7" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1717][1080,1915]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[11,1739][231,1893]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/dhh" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[44,1739][198,1893]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/yo" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[44,1739][198,1893]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/cz9" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[44,1739][198,1893]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[44,1739][198,1893]" /></node></node></node></node><node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[231,1764][753,1867]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" ch (..)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is on one line, you could do:

1. Select the line you want from your list of nodes:

   ```
   grep "com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/hzk" list.xml
   ```
2. Extract the text from that line:

   ```
   echo "$line" | sed 's/.* text="\(.*\)" resource.*/\1/'
   ```

A complete script could look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

resource_id="$1"

grep "$resource_id" list.xml | sed 's/.* text="\(.*\)" resource.*/\1/'
```

And you would call it like this:

```
./script.bash com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/hzk
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that and probably my question wasn't precious enough. The whole the xml file i get contains several nodes and is compleltly unorganized (just one big block of text). So using grep will just give me everything

Comment: I edited the original question for more clarity :)

Comment: Add code to split your long lines by adding carriage returns.  Ex. `<node` to `\n<node` and `</node>` to `</node>\n`.  Then the rest of my idea will work.